# Blazor NoobQuestion:How to shadow each keystroke entered in a <Input type="text" @bind-value.... /> live in the paragraph above?

Tags: asp.net, input, text, blazor

totaly new to Blazor/RazorPages etc.. I want to replicate the following WinForms behavior (just to explain what i want to archive)

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text= textBox1.Text;
    }
```

So when I hit any Key it shows at the "same" time in the TextBox and in the RichTextBox. The Input in Txtbx is copied instandly to the Rtxbx. I have trouble in Blazor doing that (my try):

```html
<div>@result/div> 

<div>
input type="text" @bind-value="enteredText" @oninput="ShadowText"
</div>

@code
{
    private string enteredText="";

    private void ShadowText()
    {
        result = enteredText;
    }
}
```

Sorry didn't know how to enter BlazorCode in here!?!

Is there a different @onEVENT that I should use or how do I get that task done?

I can do it with a button @onclick but I cant do it "live" per keystroke.

Thank You for you Answere/Help :)

Comment: @nogood, I've updated my first answer a little bit, so take attention. If you don't understand something, please don't hesitate to ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this perfect solution:

```
@page "/testpage"
<h1>Greetings, @userName</h1>

<input @bind-value="userName" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

 @code {
     string userName = "ChangeMyName";
  }
```

Comment: Buddy, what is perfect about your solution. This is a two-way data-binding that uses the input event instead of the change event. You post a partial answer... where is the code that updates a second input field? Did you read your question when you've posted  this answer. Please read your question once more, and then try to complete your answer so that it would do what is stated in your question, and demonstrated in my answer, so that we all can say, yes this is the perfect solution ...

Comment: How to shadow each keystroke entered in a <Input type=“text” @bind-value… /> live in the paragraph above?

Comment: Quote: Okay the code is working :) ... Could this work with only one "inputBox" and show result in a "normal" <p>@resultValue</p> way? Sorry to bother further – nogood May 19 at 20:34 -- The Code Snipet does exactly that --

Comment: The question is how do you pass the entered value form one text box to another ( richTextBox1.Text= textBox1.Text;), not how how display the value entered into a text box, which is something entirely  different. You speak of passing value into richTextBox1 which is another text box,  your code doesn't do it.

Comment: Okay you were missled by the question text. Okay, but if you honestly reread the whole thing here. It is clear that I wanted to achive exactly what the last solution is doing. The WinForms Example was just a try to explain, because I didn't know who to word the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 <p>
    <input type="text" value="@Value1" @oninput="@((args) => Value1 = 
    Value2 = args.Value.ToString())" />
 </p>

 <p>
     <input type="text" value="@Value2" @oninput="@((args) => Value2 = 
      Value1 = args.Value.ToString())" />
  </p>


  @code{

     private string value1;
     public string Value1
    {
        get => value1;
        set
        {
          if (value1 != value)
            value1 = value;
        }
     }

    private string value2;
    public string Value2
    {
       get => value2;
       set
       {
         if (value2 != value)
            value2 = value;
       }
   }
```

}

Note: Each input element is two-way data-binded (from property to element and vice versa), and both are binded to each other. When you change a value in one element it changes in the second one, and vice versa.

Hope this helps...

Comment: How is this Codebit called :   (( )  => )  is it a Lamda ?

Comment: Okay the code is working :) ... Could this work with only one "inputBox" and show result in a "normal" <p>@resultValue</p>  way? Sorry to bother further

Comment: Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful. (It's the green check sign)

Comment: Yes, (( ) => ) is  a Lambada expression

Comment: Yes, try to do it yourself. Remove one input element, and in the second do this: @oninput="@((args) => resultValue = 
   args.Value.ToString())"